# How to make a table column border as re-sizable instead of border bottom corner resize?

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table, angular13

Currently table border resizing is working when we resize this border corner. I want to make the right side full border to resizable.
[image]

Here is the resize css

```
th{
  resize: horizontal;
  overflow: auto;
 min-width: 100px!important;
 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
th {
   resize: both;
   overflow: auto;
   min-width: 100px!important;
}
```

Comment: I don't want both horizontal and vertical resize